# Change case of string, replace hyphens with spaces and capitalize first letter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to transform the following string "joe-smith" to "Joe Smith". I have the following code which seems to work okay, but is there a faster, better way?

```
var prettify = function(str){
   var temp = str.split('-'), i, pretty;

   for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
     temp[i] = temp[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp[i].slice(1);
   }

   pretty = temp.join(' ');

   return pretty;
 };

 var prettyString = prettify('joe-smith');
// outputs "Joe Smith"
```

Comment: will the string passed always be in that format? (name-lastname)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things:

- That `pretty` variable is pretty useless. Omit it.
- `temp` is quite meaningless. Use a descriptive name like `words` or `parts`.
- You could use the [Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of that for loop. This will likely be slower, but more elegant:

  ```
  function prettify(str) {
      return str.split('-').map(function capitalize(part) {
          return part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1);
      }).join(' ');
  }
  ```
- regular expressions and the [String `replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) could further shorten it, and possibly improve performance:

  ```
  function prettify(str) {
      return str.replace(/(-|^)([^-]?)/g, function(_, prep, letter) {
          return (prep && ' ') + letter.toUpperCase();
      });
  }
  ```

  Decide yourself whether this is too cryptic or not.

Comment: I like the map solution for code, but it sure is not the fast one as the map is rather expensive. The regex solution does capitalize any letter Mr functional programmer :) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noem1vtb/1/)

Comment: @MaxZoom: Thanks for the feedback, I was trying to be too clever. I used the non-greedy match for the case `joe--smith`, but a non-greedy optional in the end of a regex of course never matches anything :-/ Fixed.

Comment: I up-voted the answer for the regex, particularly for this `(prep && ' ')`

Comment: …a horrible hack that I'm not proud about :-)

Comment: So stumbled upon this searching on how to capitalize and replace hyphens and underscores from a string. Have been trying to modify the regex to match underscores as well for a while now, but no luck. Any possibility of modifying the regex solution to replace underscores as well ? Any help highly appreciated !

Comment: @Norman What regex did you try?

Comment: I tried this regex:
    `/([-_]|^)([^-_]?)/g`

But then resorted to replacing all underscores for now in the prettify function:

    `str = str.replace(/_/g, ' ');`

Comment: @Norman That one is working for me. On what input does it not work?

Answer (score 5):

It seems there is no faster way to beautify word then your code.
The only improvement could be the split method:

```js
function prettify(str) {
  var words = str.match(/([^-]+)/g) || [];
  words.forEach(function(word, i) {
    words[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  });
  return words.join(' ');
}

var prettyString = prettify('joe-smith');
alert(prettyString)
```

Comment: Please do not use meaningless identifiers like `beautify`, especially on `String.prototype`. That operation has a quite specific name.

Comment: Oh, and don't use `forEach` like that.

Comment: @Bergi  Why you don't like forEach?

Comment: Because I'm a functional programmer and don't like side effects. If you have to use array iteration methods, there is a much better suited one.

Comment: This approach seems to be more fault proof. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noem1vtb/3/)

Comment: Grmph, empty matches. It's [solvable](https://jsfiddle.net/noem1vtb/4/), but two regexes would probably be cleaner :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may be over thinking this. You can use the JavaScript replace method which take a regular expression (first parameter) and then what you want to replace it with (second parameter). then return the new string.

```
var prettify = function(str){      
    var prettyStr = str.replace(/-/, ' ');
    return prettyStr ;
};
```

Here is a revision that sets the first and last name to uppercase.

```
var prettify = function(str){      
    var splitStr = str.replace(/-/, ' ');
    var prettyStr = splitStr.replace( /\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();} );
    return prettyStr ;
};
```

The to uppercase uses the same replace but it grabs on name at a time then runs a function that takes the text capitalizes the first letter ( charAt(0) the first character in the name ) then attaches the rest of the sub-string ( substr(1) starts at the second character ).

I got the code reference from this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city

Comment: op wants capitalization as well

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make a miniature finite state machine like this one

```
function prettify(input) {
    var output = "", shouldCap = 1, c;
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        c = input[i];
        if(c == "-") {
            output += " ";
            shouldCap = 1;
        } else if(shouldCap) {
            output += c.toUpperCase();
            shouldCap = 0;
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    }    
    return output;
}

alert(prettify("logan-murphy"));
```

Also minifying your code can increase the speed since javascript is executed on the fly. I provided benchmarks of my code vs the accepted answers code. Look at the console's log to confirm the speed difference. Note that this was only tested in Chrome.

```js
var timer = (function() {
    var last;
    return function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if(last) {
            console.log(now - last);
            last = 0;
        } else {
            last = now;
        }
    };
}()), prettify;

function doTests() {
    timer();
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        prettify("logan-murphy");        
    }
    timer();
}

//accepted answer
prettify = function(str) {
    return str.split('-').map(function capitalize(part) {
        return part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1);
    }).join(' ');
};

doTests();

//my answer
prettify = function(input) {
    var output = "", shouldCap = 1, c;
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        c = input[i];
        if(c == "-") {
            output += " ";
            shouldCap = 1;
        } else if(shouldCap) {
            output += c.toUpperCase();
            shouldCap = 0;
        } else {
            output += c;
        }
    }    
    return output;
};

doTests();

//using arrays - still slower
prettify = function(input) {
    var output = new Array(input.length), shouldCap = 1, c;
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        c = input[i];
        if(c == "-") {
            output[i] = " ";
            shouldCap = 1;
        } else if(shouldCap) {
            output[i] = c.toUpperCase();
            shouldCap = 0;
        } else {
            output[i] = c;
        }
    }    
    return output.join("");
};

doTests();
```

Comment: "have to make" - for what? For better, more readable code?

Comment: Is `shouldCap` a boolean or not?

Comment: i would say its faster since it doesnt depend on regexp or any algorithm that requires an iteration over the string. also 1 and 0 are the smallest truthy/falsy values available so it doesnt have to be a boolean.

Comment: What is `for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++)` doing if not an iteraton over the string? And you are doing `shouldCap = true`, which *is* a boolean. Changing the type of the variable will likely need more memory.

Comment: @Bergi i know, but it only requires one iteration, vs other solutions that use `match`, `split`, `join` `replace`, `slice` which have multiple iterations

Comment: you answer for example requires a total of 4 iterations, one to split, another to map, another to slice, and another to finally join it back together

Comment: Ah yeah, though the `map` does not a full iteration, and I think `slice` on strings is implemented in less then `O(n)`. But not creating intermediate data structures might indeed help performance, even if your `output` buffer might be worse than a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.map()` function helps one to do this in much simpler way.

**For Example**: `share-information`.

Output will be `Share-Information`.

```
capitalize (str) { return (str) ?str.split('-')
.map(text=> text.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ word.slice(1))
.join('-') :str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);  }
```

You can use Regex value in split for multiple symbols.

**for eg:** `.split(/,-_| /)`

Comment: Welcome to Code review and thank you for contributing an answer. [Bergi's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87224/120114) already mentioned using `.map` as well as regular expressions. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "_Read the other answers so you don't cover duplicate points. While it is fine to mention points in multiple answers, each answer should contain at least one novel observation._"